# displaying levels(city/region names) on the map created with shape file using rgdal library in R

Tags: r, google-maps, plot, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I am creating a map using rgdal library using a shape file for india and able to plot data points on the india map using code below.But I am struggling to give place/level/city names on the map.

Code below is for creating map from shape file.

```
counties<-readOGR("India Map/IND_adm1.shp",layer="IND_adm1",verbose = TRUE, addCommentsToPolygons =TRUE)
```

And codes below is for plotting data point on map.

```
    ggplot() +  geom_polygon(data=counties, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), fill="grey40", 
               colour="grey90", alpha=1)+

labs(x="", y="", title="Tweet counts")+ #labels
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_blank(), # get rid of x ticks/text
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_blank(), # get rid of y ticks/text
        plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold", vjust=1))+ # make title bold and add space
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=data_frame$`count(comment)`), data=data_frame, alpha=0.5, size=3, color="grey20")+# to get outline
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=data_frame$`count(comment)`), data=data_frame, alpha=0.5, size=2)+
  scale_colour_gradientn("Tweet counts", 
                         colours=c( "#f9f3c2","#660000"))+ # change color scale
  coord_equal(ratio=1) # square plot to avoid the distortion
```

Below is the map image that created using above code on which I want to add level of city/continent/regions.[image]

I went through documentation and changes various parameters of readOGR function below to give levels on the map, still no luck.

```
readOGR(dsn, layer, verbose = TRUE, p4s=NULL, 
stringsAsFactors=default.stringsAsFactors(), 
drop_unsupported_fields=FALSE, input_field_name_encoding=NULL,
pointDropZ=FALSE, dropNULLGeometries=TRUE,
useC=TRUE, disambiguateFIDs=FALSE, addCommentsToPolygons=TRUE)
```

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? What part do you consider is not working? Is plotting even relevant at this point? Because in your code, there's no geoms for adding text...

Comment: Codes are working(shape .shp files does not display regios/city name on the map), need to write extra line of code to display the levels(city names) on the map which I am writing. Since you have mentions geom to add text I will look into it to add levels